# Navbar Hover activates on All Links when Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using a free html5 theme to build on for a website and need a bit of help with the Navbar Hover function. To view the original html5 theme go to" http://www.templatemo.com/free-website-templates/430-robotic

The theme is a onepage theme however I am converting into a multipage theme. Originally in the theme you would click a menu item and it would scroll down the page to that content but I want it to open the new page in same window for that content. The way a normal site would do so. Below is a HTML and CSS.

**HMTL**

```
<div class="templatemo_menu">
<div class="templatemo_socialmedia">
    <div class="templatemo_social">
        <a href="http://www.Facebook.com/GreenHouseEffectUSA">
            <img src="images/facebook.png" alt="templatemo facebook">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="templatemo_social">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/greenhouse_usa">
            <img src="images/twitter.png" alt="templatemo twitter">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="templatemo_social">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="images/youtube.png" alt="templatemo youtube">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="top-menu">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" wp-nav-menu="Primary" wp-nav-menu-type="bootstrap">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">HOME</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">DONATE</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">VOLUNTEER</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a
{
    color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #099742;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover
{
    background: #0a662b;
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse
{
    border: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a.first
{
    border-top: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover
{
    background: #0a662b;
    color: #fff;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the classes to the div rather than the ul